# Spring data repository projection findByEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, repository, spring-data-jpa, jpql

That is the JPA entity MyEntity.

```
Entity
class MyEntity{
    private Integer id;    
    private Date date;    
    private Double montant;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User creator;
}


    class User {
        private Integer id;    
        private String name;    
        private String image;           
        private Integer age;

        private String anotherField;
    }
```

I would like to retrieve a list of MyEntity with some attributes of its creator (just the id, the name and its image).
So I created a Projection interface.

```
interface Projection{
    public Integer getId();
    public Date getDate();
    public Double getMontant();
    public User getCreator();

    interface User {
        public Integer getId();
        public String getName();
        public String getImage();
    }
}
```

here JPA repository implementation :

```
public interface CommandeRepository extends JpaRepository<EbCommande, Integer> {

    <T> Collection<T> findById(Integer id, Class<T> type);
    <T> Collection<T> findByCreator(User client, Class<T> type);

}
```

The first query works as I hope.

On the other hand with the second, when I loop on the list of MyEntity returned, each access to the User attribute triggers a request to the database fetching all the attributes of the User.

I do not understand how JPA projections work anymore.

Help please!

Comment: 'each access to the User attribute triggers a request to the database fetching all the attributes of the User.' That's the point of lazy fetching right, only get it when you need it?

Comment: Stefan if i wasn't doing projection i would be right with you. I don't wanna fetch all user's  properties.

Comment: FWIW The JPA API has no such "Repository". That is Spring. Understand what you are using